# Does "political cause, group or politician" include national governments?

Tags: support, close-reasons, good-faith

In the Question closed message:

> The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician.

does "political cause, group or politician" include national governments such as USA or Russia?

Comment: From this answer by the moderator Philipp, I think the answer is yes: [Unfortunately your question is anything but neutral. The "Background info" does everything to make one country look good and the other bad.](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4430/19301)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it does.

We do not want political propaganda on this website. That means we don't want questions which are primarily designed to make the government of one country look good and/or another country look bad.

When you have questions about specific governments and their actions, please try to phrase them from a neutral point of view.

Avoid prejudice, polemic and [leading questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_question) when you phrase your question. ("Look here at the newest crimes against humanity the fascist government of the Arstotzkan has committed today. What wicked logic do these corrupt tyrants use to justify these atrocities?").

You might already have a very strong opinion about an issue, but don't assume that you already have all the information. If you already knew everything there is to know about a topic, then you wouldn't have to ask questions about it. So don't assume that your opinion is the only logical/ethical one to have on the subject. Try to keep your personal opinion out of the question and stay objective and neutral instead. ("The government of Arstotzka has recently enacted this law. What is the official rationale provided by the government for this policy?"). Perhaps the real answer is completely different from what you expected it to be.

Don't get me wrong: There is nothing wrong with having an opinion on something a government did. And even when it is not based on having all the facts, sharing and debating your opinions with other people can be very useful for you and everyone else. Others might have information and views you do not, so debating gives you an opportunity to refine your opinions and become a more informed citizen. **But Politics Stack Exchange is not a debate website!** That's just not what this website is for. We are a Q&A website, not a discussion forum.