# What's wrong with my Sergey Karjakin question?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75098/sergey-karjakin-re-the-alley-of-angels

Sergey is how I 1st heard of Alley of Angels, but surely Sergey isn't the only person to ever use the Alley of Angels to explain why 'Ukraine is the bad guy' right?

Is it any different if I ask 'Why does the pro-Putin side consider the events that led to the Alley of Angels an explanation of why "Ukraine is the bad guy" ?' ?

Comment: From what I understand he really isn't a political figure and wouldn't be on topic on this site.

Answer (score 6):

I wasn't one of the close votes (or downvotes), but if I saw that question today I'd vote to close it for either the 'based on speculation' or the 'not about politics' close reasons.

From what I see in the comments and from my own understanding, your question was about interpreting what exactly a non-political person meant in a broad statement about a memorial, and whether or not his commentary could be viewed as wrong in some way. Questions about what the 'pro-Putin side' thinks about some event can be on topic, however, your only example of the pro-Putin side was someone who doesn't seem particularly involved in politics.

As the [help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says, Politics is a site for "objective questions about governments, policies and political processes", and the background info you included in your question doesn't really explain how your question relates to that:

- [Sergey Karjakin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergey_Karjakin) was born in Crimea, has represented both Ukraine and Russia in chess tournaments, and has publicly voiced support for Russia's invasion of Ukraine. In short, he talks about events that affect where he's lived but he's not a politician and doesn't seem to be an activist or lobbyist, so it's not clear why his comments would give any more insight into the side he supports than comments from any other non-political person.
- The 'Alley of Angels' [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alley_of_Angels) you linked doesn't seem to exist anymore (there is [a draft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft:Alley_of_Angels) page created in November 2022), so it's not clear what the story behind this memorial is, why Karjakin would be talking about it, or why it's related to governments/politics/etc.

Overall, I believe the focus on Karjakin and what he may have meant is what made this question off-topic, and your scattered questions and speculation about a controversial topic led to the downvotes.

Questions about that 'Alley of Angels' memorial could be on topic though, if you find commentary on it from activists or politicians that better shows what one side or another believes. Just from a quick search, it seemed like it's used by various political groups to help spread their messages, so it shouldn't be too hard to find someone more involved in politics that Karjakin talking about it.

Answer (score 2):

Meh, even leaving aside all the chess-bubble minutiae that permated this and your other questions,

> Sergey is trying to say Ukraine is the villain for fighting an unjust, in Sergey's opinion, war or something?

I mean is that [really in doubt](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4723/what-is-a-push-question) given that you've also described Sergey as "Pro-Putin" in the same post?

And in case you didn't know, both sides erected/painted monuments for the children fallen in that conflict. Although Russia has [painted over](https://youtu.be/L77VRZAHGlU?t=437) some of those in the areas it took over.