# My question should be reopened because it was not a duplicate

Tags: support, closed-questions

The question needs to be reopened are: ["Conflicting Egos: what groups of people tend to support the stabilizing of federal spending on personnel?"](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/81538/conflicting-egos-what-groups-of-people-tend-to-support-the-stabilizing-of-feder)

and [Why does no one stand up to protest the strike of Canadian federal officers who are earning about 45% more than average Canadian workers?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/81508/why-does-no-one-stand-up-to-protest-the-strike-of-canadian-federal-officers-who)

I tried my best to ask a question *on topic* according to [our forum rule](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Conflicting Egos:
>
> In just about any policy of substance, there are particular
> personalities that are central to its understanding, as well as
> demographic data about supporters and opponents of legislation. Asking
> “Why is [insert person here] such a jerk?” is clearly off-topic - the
> answer is highly subjective, but asking “What groups of people tend to
> support X in her implementation of policy Y?” is answerable using
> polls, punditry, and other verifiable and reproducible sources.

If a question “What groups of people tend to support X in her implementation of policy Y?” is on topic, then my question: "Conflicting Egos: what groups of people tend to support the stabilizing of federal spending on personnel?" clear is also on topic.

In most of my questions, I tried my best to be open and incorporate the suggestions from comments and incorporate more sources. I also tried my best to clarify issues arise by the commenters. Also it seems like some commenters are trying to silence me using every possible reasons: for example, trying to falsify my "median income data" with "average salary data".

Comment: Your question already has one reopen vote, you should give it time for people to review it and cast their votes on if it should be reopened or not.

Comment: @JoeW Your downvotes and closure-vote to my previous questions were taste-based not rule-based.

Comment: This is no longer about my votes as I was not the only one to downvote or vote to close it. I was just pointing out that it was on the path to being reopened and it might help to give people time to vote on it.

Answer (score 3):

First, I suggest you read this: [What is a "push question"?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4723/what-is-a-push-question) It applies to both your Qs that got closed.

Your 2nd Q could be reopened if you removed all the distracting claims about pay etc. Which read more like you're providing an answer yourself. And if you made it more focused. Right now it asks:

> What groups of common workers tend to support the stabilizing of federal spending on personnel and dissent the strike of the Federal workers? Why did those dissentients not have any public actions or equal media presence?

The latter bit is duplicative of your earlier question:

> Why does no one stand up to protest the strike of Canadian federal officers [...]

(and yeah, the push element is right there in the title of that one "who are earning about 45% more than average Canadian workers?")

---

BTW, I'm not sure what "common workers" might mean in the Canadian context, or why that would be an interesting focus, assuming that's using the [US def](https://statutes.capitol.texas.gov/Docs/LA/htm/LA.92.htm):

> "Common worker" means an individual who performs labor involving physical tasks that do not require:
>
> (A)  a particular skill;
>
> (B)  training in a particular occupation, craft, or trade;  or
>
> (C)  practical knowledge of the principles or processes of an art, science, craft, or trade.

I mean, quite possibly unskilled workers might resent government workers in general (whom generally don't fall into the unskilled labor category), whether the gov't workers strike or not. (See e.g. the ["left behind thesis"](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/13511610.2021.1964350).) So, that "common workers" angle also seems to be a bit [leading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_question). Or maybe you're just looking for confirmation for the "left behind thesis" in this case? I'm not sure.

Although I should not be answering your main-space Q on meta, here's a relevant quote in that direction, from a [paper](https://psych.wisc.edu/Brauer/BrauerLab/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/CarpenterBrauerNiedenthal_2020.pdf) on "rural resentment of government employees":

> in a study of political attitudes, Cramer (2016b) conducted
> interviews with groups of people gathered in public spaces in the state of
> Wisconsin. The conversations revealed a distressed focus by rural and
> working-class citizens on government employees (i.e. civil servants) – including and especially public schoolteachers, professors of state universities, and
> agents of departments of natural resource management – as representatives
> of an urban agenda. Feelings of resentment toward the perceived outgroups
> appeared to be fueled by campaign rhetoric that highlighted economic disparities between government employees and “regular” taxpayers, and interpreted the attainment of a so-called job for life as an unfair and undeserved
> advantage (Cramer 2016a, 2016b).

Comment: And when that average is defined as the median of the bottom 50% it brings in even more questions.

Comment: @JoeW I never defined average as "median of bottom 50%". My data has sources and their methodologies are clear.

Comment: @dodo You used it in your question to compare the salaries of the groups in question which is the problem.